# How to display my country's map?

Tags: cartography, references, display, geomajas

I am newbie in Geomajas and I tried to create new Geomajas application using the documentation in http://files.geomajas.org/maven/trunk/geomajas/docbook-gettingstarted/html/master.html.

I don't know how to display my country's map (Mongolia) in my created Geomajas application. Can you tell me how to do that or do you have any step by step guide/tutorial on this issue?

Please help me

Answer (score 2):

If you have the application up and running, the first steps would be adding some data. If you have data in a shapefile, wfs service or database you can follow the geotools layer documentation to add this data into your application. See the documentation: http://files.geomajas.org/maven/trunk/geomajas/geomajas-layer-geotools-documentation/html/master.html for further details.

In the archetype there is already a shapefile configured, so you have an example there on how to configure the definition.

The main steps for a vectorlayer are:

1. Configure your server layer in Spring (layer.xml): the actual Layer (ShapeInMemLayer, GeotoolsLayer,...).
2. Configure your client layer in Spring: this results typically in clientLayer.xml and layer.xml
3. Add the layers to the map configuration (mapMain.xml, refer to your clientVectorLayerInfo)

that should do the trick.

To limit the map bounds to only your country, have a look at initialBounds on the map configuration.

Also, don't hesitate to ask things on the geomajas mailing list, they are really helpful there. Cheers.